# Selecting a value of a column in LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have query in link to SQL like this

```
var password = (from userAccounts in myDb.Physicians
                            where userAccounts.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                            select userAccounts).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to select a specific column with that query, I want to retrieve the row value of `userAccounts.Password`,  `userAccounts.Phy_FName`, `userAccounts.Phy_Password` and so on.

is `password.Phy_FName` allowed? assuming that we have a result? how do I select  a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it right. your `Phy_UserName` needs to be a column in your database. It's returning a `Physicians` object and you can get each value as follows.

```
// `var physician` is the same as `Physician physician` 
// where you're declaring a Physician object from your DBML file

// we're using `p` for `physician` in the lambda select function
var physician = (from p in myDb.Physicians
                 where p.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();

// now that you've got a `physician` object, you can use the properties
// within the object as follows..
var password = physician.Password;
var firstName = physician.Phy_FName;
// etc

// please note that the physician object you have currently has ALL of the 
// database fields for that particular physician
```

now if you choose to only select your needed properties, you will approach it a little differently.

```
// first you declare a poco to store only the needed properties.

public class PhysicianViewModel {
    public string Password {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}

// then you run your select query and drill down to grab
// only the required data fields from the database
var physicianViewModel = (from p in myDb.Physicians
                          where userAccounts.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                          select new PhysicianViewModel { 
                              Password = p.Password,
                              FirstName = p.Phy_FName }).FirstOrDefault();

// and using them is the same as the above example
// the only difference here is that the `physicianViewModel` doesn't 
// contain ANY properties other than the ones you specified.
var password = physicianViewModel.Password;
var firstName = physicianViewModel.FirstName;
```

---

#### Edit

As per your comment below, this is a little aside pertaining to preventing a `null` value being inserted into a `string` (`nvarchar`) field in the database.

The easiest way to do this is to add the required attribute to the property and ensure you're validating it before submitting it.

```
public class Physician {
    [Required]
    public string Password {get; set;}
    public string Phy_FName {get; set;}
    public string Phy_LName {get; set;}
}
```

If you set the allow null to `false` in the database, and then update your DBML file to reflect the changes, then the `[required]` attribute will be added to the property automatically.

Comment: but what if the firstName is null how would change or prevent it from adding a null value?

Comment: if your firstName property is a `string`, then it shouldn't be a problem `System.String` is a reference type and is already nullable.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the **input** is never Null, then you need to make sure that your database does not allow `null`, and then update your dbml file. By doing that, there will be a `[required]` attribute added to the property preventing it from having `null` values submitted. In this specific question however, you're looking to pull data out of the datbase, so it's sort of a different topic.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little more details for you. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var physician = (from p in myDb.Physicians
                 where p.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();

var password = physician.Password;
var fName = physician.Phy_FName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var password = (from userAccounts in myDb.Physicians
                 where userAccounts.Phy_UserName == txtUserName.Text
                 select new { 
                          Password = physician.Password,
                          FullName = physician.Phy_FName  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: As an explanation as to what @allentranks is doing, he's selecting ONLY the `Password` and the `Phy_FName` from the database... this is good as to not query the entire row but rather just the required data. You should make sure that the `var password` actually points to some POCO that you can use later down the chain.